# Application of algorithm to sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

I got this puzzle from a professor.

Suppose that we have a sequence $a_1$, $a_2$, .., $a_{200}$ $= 1, -1, 0, ..., 0$ where we have $198$ zeros.

Now, we perform this algorithm: we replace $a_i$ with $a_i$ + $a_{i+1}$ and $a_{200}$ is replace with $a_1$+$a_{200}$.

We must now prove that there is at least one term that, if we apply the algorithm indefinitely, will increase to either infinity or negative infinity.

Observing smaller cases, I'm getting that it eventually goes to positive infinity, and I think induction may work out, but I am not sure how to prove using induction. I am not sure how to do it any other way.

Comment: Are all assignments $a_i \leftarrow a_i + a_{1+(i \mod 200)}$ done simultaneously or in the order of increasing $i$?

Comment: simultaneously.